# General Purpose Map of struct via interface{} in golang

Tags: go

I have 2 types of struct based on 3rdparties code that I cant change

```
type AddEvent struct {
}

type DeleteEvent struct {
}
```

I would like to create a map of string as key and Object as value
so each time I got new event I will add it to the map I.E
Map should look like this:

```
EventMap:
    event1,AddEvent{}
    event2,AddEvent{}
    event2,DeleteEvent{}
```

The issue that AddEvent and DeleteEvent are not defined as interfaces.
Is there I way to create a generic map in go using any struct as a value and in case yes, how can I read it do I need to check the type using reflect

```
I.E
event:=EventMap[event1]
if reflect.TypeOf(event)==AddEvent{
}else if reflect.TypeOf(event)==DeleteEvent{
}
```

Comment: You can use `map[string]interface{}` i.e. a map of empty interfaces, and to read it you can use type assertion. E.g. `ae, ok := m["add_event"].(AddEvent)`.

Comment: As soon as you implement this function as described here and the answer below anything may be added to the map as it is now typeless. This is not bad but instead of letting the language validate the types... you have to do it... either when adding the events or when pulling them off.

Comment: That you called these "EVENTS" suggests that these are events. Just for clarification MAPS should not be used as a QUEUE. These serve different purposes and have different use-cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what comment says looks good, but missing `type switch`. Full version maybe you need is:

```
m := make(map[string]interface{})
addEvent := new(AddEvent)
m["event1"] = addEvent
switch m["event1"].(type) {
case *AddEvent:
    // do something
case *DeleteEvent:
    // do other things
}
```

Comment: Thanks worked:) but should not use pointer  case *AddEvent: replaced by case AddEvent:

Comment: it's better to use pointer reference, unless you need to get a copy of struct.

Comment: agree as i can also change the struct

Comment: you may need to add the DEFAULT case if you need to make sure junk was not added to the list.